# Redshift SqlActivity : How to reference input and output in script

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline

I have a Datapipeline where I'm using a Redshift `SqlActivity` that read from a Redshift table and write in another Redshift table.
I would like to know if it is possible to reference the `input` and `output` field from the `SqlActivity`

e.g

```
INSERT INTO #{output1} (field1, field2)
SELECT field1, SUM(field2)
FROM #{input1}
GROUP BY field1;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Your query will look like

```
INSERT INTO #{output.tableName} (field1, field2)
SELECT field1, SUM(field2)
FROM #{input.tableName}
GROUP BY field1;
```